# Unable to parse date using ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, java-8, zoneddatetime

Does anyone know how to parse this format of date using ZonedDateTime.
2017-03-26T06:06:09.000+0000

```
 private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.zzz+zzz";

    public void  converDate()
    {
        String dateInString = "2017-03-26T06:06:09.000+0000";
        ZonedDateTime ldt = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateInString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT));
        System.out.println(ldt.toString());
    }
```

I have this code but this gives an exception. Unable to parse. I don't have DateFormatter correct.

Does anyone know how to use Formatter.

Answer (score 1):

The datetimeformat should be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

> S       fraction-of-second          fraction          978
>   Z   zone-offset                 offset-Z          +0000; -0800; -08:00;

Detail at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Answer (score 0):

In your pattern instead of using 'S' to parse the fraction-of-second you used 'z'.
'z' is used for time-zone name.
See javadoc [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)

The correct pattern is ""yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS+SSSS" and whilke creating the DateTimeFormatter you need to pass zoneId.

Here is the working Code:

```
private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS+SSSS";
public void converDate(){
    String dateInString = "2017-03-26T06:06:09.000+0000";
    ZonedDateTime ldt = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateInString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT).withZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin")));

    System.out.println(ldt.toString());

}
```